# Spring JpaRepository save causes 100s of selects to be generated

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Im getting very strange error when I call save on a JpaRepository.
The code seems trivial so i can only think its something to do with configuration.

Basically I call a findBy method on the repository, this returns a list of dao objects exactly as expected, I go through this list setting a timestamp then calling save() on each dao, as soon as the first save is called the log is filled with hundreds of identical select statements, selecting on the dao I'm just trying to save until eventually there is a stack overflow.
What could cause this ???
(note originally I called saveAll() on the list of dao objects - this, unsurprisingly has the same error )

```
  public void triggerDeletion() {
        ZonedDateTime expiryDate = ZonedDateTime.now().minus(daysAfterExpiry);
        // Get list of conversations to delete
        List<ConversationDao> conversationDaoList = conversationDatabaseService.retrieveExpiredConversations(expiryDate);
        // Mark each conversation as deleted by setting its deletion timestamp to now.
        conversationDaoList.stream().forEach(conversation->delete(conversation));

    }
    public  void delete(ConversationDao conversationDao){
        conversationDao.setDeletionTimestamp(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        conversationDatabaseService.save( conversationDao );   <------ This generates 100s of select statements.
    }
    ...
// ConversationDatabaseService Interface
////////////////////////////////////////

public interface ConversationDatabaseService {   
    void save(ConversationDao conversationDao); 

}
...
// Conversation DatabaseService Class
/////////////////////////////////////

@Service
public class ConversationDatabaseServiceImpl implements ConversationDatabaseService {

    private final ConversationRepository conversationRepository;

    public void save(ConversationDao conversationDao) {

    conversationRepository.saveAndFlush(conversationDao);  // Just save has also been tried.
}

}
... 
// ConversationRepository interface
///////////////////////////////////

public interface ConversationRepository extends JpaRepository<ConversationDao, String> {

    List<ConversationDao> findByExpiryDateLessThanAndDeletionTimestampIsNull(Timestamp expiryDate);
}
...
// ConversationDao
//////////////////////////////////

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCX_CONVERSATION")
public class ConversationDao {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2",
        strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "CONVERSATION_ID",
        columnDefinition = "char")
    private String conversationId;

    @Column(name = "PROCESS_CODE")
    private String processCode;

    @Column(name = "PROFILE_ID",
        columnDefinition = "char")
    private String profileId;

    @Column(name = "REMINDER_EMAIL_SENT",
        columnDefinition = "char")
    private String reminderEmailSent;

    @Column(name = "EXPIRY_DATE")
    private Date expiryDate;

    @Column(name = "DELETION_TIMESTAMP")
    private Timestamp deletionTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "LAST_LOGIN_TIMESTAMP")
    private Timestamp lastLoginTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_USER_ID",
        columnDefinition = "char")
    private String colleagueId;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_TIMESTAMP",
        updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp createdTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_USER_ID",
        columnDefinition = "char")
    private String lastUpdatedUserId;

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp lastUpdatedTimestamp;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "conversation",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MessageDetailDao> messageDetailDaoSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fileDetailId.conversation",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<FileDetailDao> fileDetailDaoSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "conversation",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ParameterDao> parameterDaoSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "conversation",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<NotificationDao> notificationDaoSet = new HashSet<>();

    public ConversationDao() {
    }

    public ConversationDao(String processCode, Date expiryDate,
        String colleagueId, String lastUpdatedUserId) {
        this.processCode = processCode;
        this.reminderEmailSent = "N";
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
        this.colleagueId = colleagueId;
        this.lastUpdatedUserId = lastUpdatedUserId;
    }

    public String getConversationId() {
        return conversationId;
    }

    public void setConversationId(String conversationId) {
        this.conversationId = conversationId;
    }

    public String getProcessCode() {
        return processCode;
    }

    public void setProcessCode(String processCode) {
        this.processCode = processCode;
    }

    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

    public String getReminderEmailSent() {
        return reminderEmailSent;
    }

    public void setReminderEmailSent(String reminderEmailSent) {
        this.reminderEmailSent = reminderEmailSent;
    }

    public Date getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(Date expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }

    public Timestamp getDeletionTimestamp() {
        return deletionTimestamp;
    }

    public void setDeletionTimestamp(Timestamp deletionTimestamp) {
        this.deletionTimestamp = deletionTimestamp;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastLoginTimestamp() {
        return lastLoginTimestamp;
    }

    public void setLastLoginTimestamp(Timestamp lastLoginTimestamp) {
        this.lastLoginTimestamp = lastLoginTimestamp;
    }

    public String getColleagueId() {
        return colleagueId.trim();
    }

    public void setColleagueId(String colleagueId) {
        this.colleagueId = colleagueId;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedTimestamp() {
        return createdTimestamp;
    }

    public void setCreatedTimestamp(Timestamp createdTimestamp) {
        this.createdTimestamp = createdTimestamp;
    }

    public String getLastUpdatedUserId() {
        return lastUpdatedUserId;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedUserId(String lastUpdatedUserId) {
        this.lastUpdatedUserId = lastUpdatedUserId;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastUpdatedTimestamp() {
        return lastUpdatedTimestamp;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedTimestamp(Timestamp lastUpdatedTimestamp) {
        this.lastUpdatedTimestamp = lastUpdatedTimestamp;
    }

    public void addMessageDetailDao(MessageDetailDao messageDetailDao) {
        messageDetailDaoSet.add(messageDetailDao);
        messageDetailDao.setConversation(this);
    }

    public Set<MessageDetailDao> getMessageDetailDao() {
        return messageDetailDaoSet;
    }

    public void addFileDetailDao(FileDetailDao fileDetailDao) {
        fileDetailDaoSet.add(fileDetailDao);
        fileDetailDao.getId().setConversation(this);
    }

    public Set<FileDetailDao> getFileDetailDao() {
        return fileDetailDaoSet;
    }

    public void addParameterDao(ParameterDao parameterDao) {
        parameterDaoSet.add(parameterDao);
        parameterDao.setConversation(this);
    }

    public Set<ParameterDao> getParameterDao() {
        return parameterDaoSet;
    }

    public void addNotificationDao(NotificationDao notificationDao) {
        notificationDaoSet.add(notificationDao);
        notificationDao.setConversation(this);
    }

    public Set<NotificationDao> getNotificationDao() {
        return notificationDaoSet;
    }
}
```

}

This generates these same select statements 100s of times before blowing the stack :-

```
1TS="20190411.075004.028" 4MSG="binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [6df49d6f-216b-460d-9282-2d25c098f9fe]" 1EVC="TRACE" 2CLS="BasicBinder"
1TS="20190411.075004.065" 4MSG="extracted value ([convers16_10_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [6df49d6f-216b-460d-9282-2d25c098f9fe]" 1EVC="TRACE" 2CLS="BasicExtractor"
1TS="20190411.075004.069" 4MSG="extracted value ([file_met1_10_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [4E90FD20-FC59-41B8-BF8E-88B7D682A87C]" 1EVC="TRACE" 2CLS="BasicExtractor"
1TS="20190411.075004.074" 4MSG="select conversati0_.conversation_id as conversa1_5_1_, conversati0_.created_user_id as created_2_5_1_, conversati0_.created_timestamp as created_3_5_1_, conversati0_.deletion_timestamp as deletion4_5_1_, conversati0_.expiry_date as expiry_d5_5_1_, conversati0_.last_login_timestamp as last_log6_5_1_, conversati0_.last_updated_timestamp as last_upd7_5_1_, conversati0_.last_updated_user_id as last_upd8_5_1_, conversati0_.process_code as process_9_5_1_, conversati0_.profile_id as profile10_5_1_, conversati0_.reminder_email_sent as reminde11_5_1_, filedetail1_.conversation_id as convers16_10_3_, filedetail1_.file_metadata_id as file_met1_10_3_, filedetail1_.conversation_id as convers16_10_0_, filedetail1_.file_metadata_id as file_met1_10_0_, filedetail1_.application_id as applicat2_10_0_, filedetail1_.case_id as case_id3_10_0_, filedetail1_.created_user_id as created_4_10_0_, filedetail1_.content_type as content_5_10_0_, filedetail1_.created_by as created_6_10_0_, filedetail1_.created_timestamp as created_7_10_0_, filedetail1_.document_code as document8_10_0_, filedetail1_.document_owner as document9_10_0_, filedetail1_.document_repository_state as documen10_10_0_, filedetail1_.file_name as file_na11_10_0_, filedetail1_.file_size_bytes as file_si12_10_0_, filedetail1_.file_state as file_st13_10_0_, filedetail1_.file_version as file_ve14_10_0_, filedetail1_.updated_by as updated15_10_0_ from docx_conversation conversati0_ left outer join docx_file_detail filedetail1_ on conversati0_.conversation_id=filedetail1_.conversation_id where conversati0_.conversation_id=?" 1EVC="DEBUG" 2CLS="SQL"
```

What is going on ??

Some more information, the cause is definitely connected to this part of the dao :-

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fileDetailId.conversation",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<FileDetailDao> fileDetailDaoSet = new HashSet<>();
```

The FileDetailDao contains an embedded reference to a FileDetailId

```
@EmbeddedId
private FileDetailId fileDetailId;
```

And this FileDetailId contains a reference to the conversationId of the join :-

```
@Embeddable
public class FileDetailId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "FILE_METADATA_ID", columnDefinition = "char")
    private String fileMetadataId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONVERSATION_ID")
    private ConversationDao conversation;
//etc
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure why but if I change the cascade type to REMOVE it works ok....

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fileDetailId.conversation",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)

private Set<FileDetailDao> fileDetailDaoSet = new HashSet<>();
```